# Resilience4j Retry module in Spring Cloud Circuitbreaker

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-webflux, resilience4j, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

I'm trying to migrate my Spring Boot 2 Resilience4j implementation to the one provided by Spring Cloud Circuitbreaker.

So basically, from ***resilience4j-spring-boot2 + resilience4j-reactor*** dependencies to ***spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j*** dependency.

According to Spring Cloud documentation, I found out that it was possible to configure the ***CircuitBreaker*** (containing the ***TimeLimiter*** module) and the ***Bulkhead*** modules of Resilience4j through customizers.

However, I don't see any configuration available for the ***Retry*** and ***RateLimiter*** modules, that are available features in R4J documentation.

Is there a way to configure those modules directly with Spring Cloud Circuitbreaker so they are part of the ReactiveCircuitBreakerFactory? Or do I still need to configure a RetryRegistry appart from it?

Answer (score 0):

`spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j` comes with the following dependencies:

- `org.springframework.cloud.spring-cloud-starter`
- `org.springframework.cloud.spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-resilience4j`
- `io.github.resilience4j.resilience4j-circuitbreaker`
- `io.github.resilience4j.resilience4j-timelimiter`
- `io.github.resilience4j.resilience4j-reactor`

If you need any of the other features from `resilience4j` like `bulkhead` or `retry`, you'll have to add them to your dependencies.

Ref: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/blob/main/spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker/spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-reactor-resilience4j/pom.xml